# Primefaces Conditionally Expand LayoutUnit

Tags: primefaces

I'm using the primefaces layout component and have a center and a right layoutUnit.  I would like to have a link/button in the center layout that expands the right layoutUnit as I default the right layout to collapsed state when I first load the page.  I'm using a boolean expression on the right layoutUnit and I update it from my link. Everything works except that the right layoutUnit doesn't get ajaxed updated from my link.  If I refresh the page the right layoutUnit is expanded.

page:

```
    <h:form prependId="false"> 
        <p:layout fullPage="true">  
            <p:layoutUnit id="right" position="right" width="350" header="Marker Details" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true" collapsed="#{mapBean.rightCollapsed}">  
                <h:outputText value="#{mapBean.text}" />  
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <p:commandLink actionListener="#{mapBean.showDetail}" update="right" value="Expand Right Layout"/>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </h:form>
```

Bean:

```
public class MapBean implements Serializable {
     private boolean rightCollapsed=true;
     public void showDetail(ActionEvent e){
        rightCollapsed=false;
     }
    //getter/setter for rightCollapsed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following forum post about using the `<p:layout>` component with the `fullPage=true` attribute.

http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4766

You cannot wrap the layout component in a form like this, each `<p:layoutUnit>` needs its own nested form.  You can still `update` the components of the other forms by setting the form id and referring to component ids correctly as another answer had suggested.  Try something like this:

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">  
  <p:layoutUnit id="right" position="right" width="350" header="Marker Details" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true" collapsed="#{mapBean.rightCollapsed}"> 
    <h:form id="rightForm" prependId="false">
      <h:outputText id="mapBeanTextOutputText" value="#{mapBean.text}" />
    </h:form>
  </p:layoutUnit>
  <p:layoutUnit position="center">
    <h:form id="centerForm" prependId="false">
      <p:commandLink actionListener="#{mapBean.showDetail}" update="mapBeanTextOutputText" value="Expand Right Layout"/>
    </h:form>
  </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is maybe  that you have not update the layout. You can give the **h:form** a **id** ,and use this id replace the commandbutton's **update** id name ,like this:

```
<h:form id="layoutForm" prependId="false">
<p:layout fullPage="true">  
            <p:layoutUnit id="right" position="right" width="350" header="Marker Details" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true" collapsed="#{mapBean.rightCollapsed}">  
                <h:outputText value="#{mapBean.text}" />  
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <p:commandLink actionListener="#{mapBean.showDetail}" update="layoutForm" value="Expand Right Layout"/>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout> 
</form>
```